# Double free issue with global map compiled in to multiple shared objects

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, shared-libraries

I have a huge map that is needed in multiple shared objects ..

```
//mymap.h
extern const std::unordered_map<int, std::string> gMAP;
std::string getname(int i) { return gMAP[i]; }

//mymap.cpp
extern const std::unordered_map<int, std::string> gMAP = {
  {1, "one" },
  {2, "two" },
  {3, "three" },
  ...
}
```

And then I have library1 (lib1.so):

```
//CMakeLists.txt lib1.so
add_library(lib1 SHARED lib1.cpp mymap.cpp)

//lib1.cpp
#include "mymap.h"
void lib1_dosomething(int i) { std::cout << getname(i) << std::endl; }
```

And then I have library2 (lib2.so):

```
//CMakeLists.txt lib2.so
add_library(lib2 SHARED lib2.cpp mymap.cpp)

//lib2.cpp
#include "mymap.h"
void lib1_dosomething(int i) { std::cout << getname(i) << std::endl; }
```

This is simply pseudo code of our complex and much bigger system. Note that not all the libraries in our system need the map. Only very few (which is why I went for compiling in the project itself).

My understanding of making it this way is as follows:

1. Each library that compiles "mymap.cpp" has a 'new' instance of the map
2. There shall be no conflicts when all the libraries are loaded into memory when the system runs. And each library creates the global map when it is loaded and destroys it when it is unloaded from memory.

So my first question is: Is this understanding correct ?

But, I see a problem during the shutdown of our system. I noticed that each library creates an instance as expected, and destroys its instance during unloading. But one library seems to call the destructor of the std::unordered_map twice. And as a result we see a deallocation error (double free or corruption (!prev)), which i cannot explain why and what is causing this. Any ideas ?

I am thinking of compiling the map in a shared library of itself, so that we only have absolutely one instance throughout the system, but i want to understand why I see the "double free or corruption (!prev)" error.

Comment: MyMap.cpp should not go in both libs. Can you put it in just one?

Comment: This is a violation of the one definition rule. No compile-time diagnostic required.

Comment: Thanks for the hint .. May be this is what I was looking for to relate the things and the behavior (undefined) I am seeing.

Comment: For reference here once again an excerpt from CPP reference: "One and only one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used (see below) is required to appear in the entire program (including any standard and user-defined libraries)."